# passing variable in functions php

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code where i insert post details to mysql and another function to add photo details to mysql. how can i get the last insert id of the post to insert into the photos table as post_id

```
function add_img($whichimg,$title)
{
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO photos (post_id,title, src) VALUES ('$this->$postid','$title','$whichimg')";
    $add_to_db = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    return $add_to_db;
}

function add_post($subject,$content)
{
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (subject, content) VALUES ('$subject','$content')";
    $add_to_db = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $postid=$mysqli->insert_id;

}
```

add_post is called first.. add_img is called several times afterwards depending on the number of photos

Is there a way to call thi $id in this function onto another ?

SOLVED IT WITH
$this->id;

Comment: I don't use mysqli - I've moved from mysql extensions straight to PDO. However, in some old code I have, I find the following immediately following an insert query. `$threadId = mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: Thanks. the problem for me is to get that $threadID to be inserted into the other table. how can i call it in another function .. im assuming something like this->threadID .. ddnt work though

Comment: A pleasure. I'm guessing that the 2nd function is called first. In that case, simply return the value that mysql_insert_id gives you. Then, as Sasanka Panguluri has suggested, use that return value as one of the parameters for add_img. I.e `add_img($whichimg, $title, $postId)`

Answer (score 1):

Accept another argument for `function add_img($whichimg,$title)`

As

```
   function add_img($whichimg,$title,$postid)
```

Since your add_img needs `$postid`, you should return it from `add_post($subject,$content)`
Inside the function, Instead of `$postid=$mysqli->insert_id;` , just say `return $mysqli->insert_id;`

Finally, When you call these methods, make sure you do this:

```
$id = add_post(<...>,<...>);
add_img(<...>,<...>,$id);
```

Comment: hi. THANKS.. i am now able to get the insert id.. im having trouble getting that and using it in another function.. As my the posts and photos are handled in differnt functions

Comment: i inserted a part of the code block on to the description if it helps